# Light locker no longer blanks screen or puts monitor into energy saving mode

Tags: xubuntu, screensaver, light-locker

I'm on Xubuntu 14.04. When I originally upgraded, I had the problem of both light locker and xscreensaver running simultaneously. After that was fixed, light locker has been running smoothly.

But, recently, I noticed my screen on after I was gone all day; it was on when I woke up the next morning; etc.

I tried changing settings, rebooting, looking for other screensaver-like processes, checking that the command args would update when I made changes in the settings UI, etc.

I can manually lock the screen with `light-locker-command -l`, but I don't remember to do that every time.

I wasn't able to find other askubuntu questions that address my situation.

Could there have been a problem with a recent update (I apply them appx. once/week)? Or, are there other things I should check?

Comment: I've since upgraded to Xubuntu 16.04 and have this same problem. I don't have xscreensaver installed (and it's not running). `light-locker` is running and I've tried updating, re-editing screensaver settings, and rebooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to xscreensaver.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove light-locker
$ pkill light-locker
$ sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

Edit the screensaver settings (click yes/okay if asked to start the daemon):

```
$ xscreensaver-demo
```

Open the XFCE Power Manager ("Power Manager" from the "Settings" menu) and  de-select "Handle display power management" in the "Display" tab.

Comment: Blanks the screen, but doesn't put the monitor into power saver mode (no matter what combination of xscreensaver and XFCE power manager settings I try)

Comment: I can force power save mode with `xset dpms force suspend`

Comment: Ah, problem might have been that I didn't kill light-locker after removing it (I updated the solution). I have power options set in both xscreensaver and XFCE power manager and it is working consistently. I think it's xscreensaver that is putting the screen into power saving mode because I have short times in xscreensaver and longer ones in XFCE PM and the screen goes into power save mode quickly.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Xubuntu 18.04 LTS, thanks @jrennie

Answer (score -1):

I found this suggestion on a discussion group, but can't find the reference at the moment (thank you to whoever suggested it!)

1. Log out
2. Switch to a terminal (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F1)
3. Log in to the text terminal
4. `$ rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions/*`
5. `$ exit`
6. Return to the graphical environment (Alt-F7)
7. Log in as normal

Now, I'm getting screen saver & locking as configured via the xfce4 power manager.

Comment: Worked at first, but I came back the next morning with my screen completely on :-(